# Openshift - Execution of post execute step failed

Tags: openshift

I have **node.js** app and during the deployment after installing dependencies the following error had occured:

```
error: Execution of post execute step failed
warning: Failed to remove container "a167df5e218c392e42ec772d5c22311f88043ff99c71ce1a08e7af535ac3817b": Error response from daemon: {"message":"Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem a167df5e218c392e42ec772d5c22311f88043ff99c71ce1a08e7af535ac3817b: Device is Busy"}
error: build error: building my-pokus/hello-seattle-2:d4b8ecde failed when committing the image due to error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Answer (score 0):

So that happens when node that the build is scheduled on, is being shutdown or restarted. Try to re-spin the build so the scheduler will, put it on an available node.
Should work :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your image is too big, if the commit is longer than 2mins, this error happens.

I found a workaround here : [github origin 13515](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13515)

> Shrink your Docker Image :)
>
> Use a more recent S2I-Builder:
>
> In order to temporarily use another version of the docker image, the
>   easiest way seems to be to simply pull the new image and tag it as the
>   one used by openshift:

```
docker pull docker.io/openshift/origin-sti-builder:v1.5.0-rc.0
docker tag docker.io/openshift/origin-sti-builder:v1.5.0-rc.0 docker.io/openshift/origin-sti-builder:v1.4.1
```